# running selenium xvfb on ubuntu 11.04

Tags: java, selenium, ubuntu-11.04

i am trying to run selenium test using maven on ubuntu. i have the following configuration for maven :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
        <executions>
              <execution>
                    <id>xvfb</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xvfb</goal>
                    </goals>
              </execution>
         <execution>
         <id>start-selenium</id>
         <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
         <goals>
             <goal>start-server</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
                      <background>true</background>
                      <port>9876</port>
         </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

i have installed xvfb from synaptic manager. but not sure if i need to setup more things. could anyone kindly show me some light please.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a configuration which is almost exactly the same which is running successfully with the version 1.1 of selenium-maven-plugin. Maybe you could test this older version. What error message are you getting?